# How to typeset LaTeX math proofs on cstheory

Tags: discussion, math

What is the best way to typeset a proof on cstheory using MathML?

I have seen the trick using \over but it does not work well if the proof is several lines long and each rule has a name like:

$$
{{X \over Y}{A} \over Z}{B}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Aren't we typesetting latex in cstheory all the time ?

Comment: @Suresh, I mean a formal proof tree like the example I gave. In LaTeX we can use packages (I use Paul Taylor and Sam Buss's packages), but I don't think that would work with MathML.

Answer (score 1):

Using core latex – I just discovered that you can define new commands –, I'd write

```
\newcommand{\infer}[3]{\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ \hline #2 \end{array}{#3}}
\infer{
    \infer{\quad X\quad}{Y}{A}}
  {Z}{B}
```

which gives

$\newcommand{\infer}[3]{\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ \hline #2 \end{array}{#3}}
\infer{
  \infer{\quad X\quad}{Y}{A}}
{Z}{B}
$

I still need to work out how to deal with the labels. \raisebox doesn't work.

If doing this in a paper, I'd use a package such as Remy's [**proof**](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by searching for mathpartir - what is it's connection to the \usepacakge{proof} that I am used to?

Comment: It seems to be a companion package. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but it doesn't render much better than mine. A should be above B and the lines should have similar lengths. I will try to take a look at Neel's posts to see if he has a better way.

Comment: @Kaveh: If you give a good specification of what you want, we can match it. I thought you wanted to avoid the small-sized X and Y. I've proposed a fix, though it isn't very good yet.

Comment: The ideal would be something like what one gets from Paul Taylor or Sam Buss's packages for proof trees but I guess that is probably not possible on cstheory. If you can make A and B appear at the same location with respect to their rules and make the lines of the same length without too much code that would be great.